# Security Sandbox Violation by a Bitmap in a Flex AIR desktop application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
SecurityDomain 'file:///Users/Bluebird/Desktop/Demo/Project/Level_01
/Background.png' tried to access incompatible context 'app:/project.swf'
```

I understand that these "security" alerts are difficult to track down and even more difficult with scant information but I thought I would ask.

I have a large Flex/AIR desktop project where the user can select images off their local drive and collage them. There are also some `swfs` provided which they can use as "stamps". I am getting the error below when stamps are added to the app and clicked – the stamps have eventListeners attached – but the error does not reference the stamp (swf) but instead it references the background image.

The background image is a `Spark Image` defined in MXML:

```
<s:Image id="backgroundImage" x="{renderX}" y="{renderY}" 
         width="{renderWidth}" height="{renderHeight}" 
         smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high" scaleMode="stretch" 
         complete="backgroundImage_completeHandler(event)" />
```

The `complete` function does nothing important. The `source` property for the image is defined once the user has selected a local image:

```
      backgroundImage.source = userFile.url
```

I don't see anywhere to provide a `loaderContext`for the `Image` component (one solution usually suggested for "security" errors). Also, the backgroundImage component has no eventListeners – so I am completely baffled why it is throwing an error.

I've set the Flex compiler option to `-use-network = false` since this is just a desktop app and that is another commonly suggested "security" fix. I am also loading the "stamp" swfs through the trick of loading them as a `byteArray` first – another commonly suggested "security" fix.

Can someone help me hate Flash a little less?

Answer (score 0):

For a quick check and probably fix, Instead the following line:-

```
backgroundImage.source = userFile.url
```

Trying giving it the relative path to the image file instead full absolute path.
like:

```
backgroundImage.source = "../images/bg.png";
```

Also, I assume you have already provided Security.allowDomain("*") in your stamp swfs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, per the [`Loader` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html), if you include the swf in the installed application content there won't be any security restrictions when loading it.

Otherwise, the `Image` component extends [`SWFLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html) which does have a `loaderContext` property. Try passing in the current domain:

```
new LoaderContext(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, SecurityDomain.currentDomain)
```